# intellij how to change run window width

Tags: intellij-idea

Something so easy..

I just want the 'run' window of intellij, that prints output, to wrap instead of just running off the side of the screen. I've spent 15 minutes trying to figure it out. Please someone tell me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea X will have this very feature. You can give the preview a try: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/index.html. You'll notice a button in the run window tool bar that says 'Use Soft Wraps'. That's what you're looking for